# What (if anything) is the significance of "2007-12-03T10:15:30.00Z" in the Java date/time parse examples?

Tags: java, java-time

I've noticed that the various Java time `parse` methods (such as `ZonedDateTime.parse(...)`) consistently use the relevant portions of `2007-12-03T10:15:30+01:00[Europe/Paris]` as the example in their Javadocs (with the exception of `Instant` which uses UTC as the time zone).

> Obtains an instance of `ZonedDateTime` from a text string such as `2007-12-03T10:15:30+01:00[Europe/Paris]`.

| Class | Example |
| --- | --- |
| [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence)) | `2007-12-03T10:15:30.00Z` |
| [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence)) | `2007-12-03` |
| [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence)) | `2007-12-03T10:15:30` |
| [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence)) | `10:15` |
| [`MonthDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/MonthDay.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence)) | `--12-03` |
| [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence)) | `2007-12-03T10:15:30+01:00` |
| [`OffsetTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetTime.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence)) | `10:15:30+01:00` |
| [`Year`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Year.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence)) | `2007` |
| [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence)) | `2007-12` |
| [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence)) | `2007-12-03T10:15:30+01:00[Europe/Paris]` |

I realize this might just be an arbitrary date, but I've found in the past that oftentime the example values have additional meaning that help my understanding of the overall domain, beyond being just an example.

Is there any particular significance to this datetime, and why was it chosen as the example parse value for the Java time API?

I'm looking specifically for something that can be backed up with something concrete (e.g. official implementation discussions or statements by those involved in the library creation).

Comment: maybe the time the author started writing the documentation or the method.

Comment: Umberto Eco would probably think up some conspiracy theory ;-)

Comment: It's not the value but the format that matters in this example.

Comment: They have to use _some_ value. Why not that one?

Comment: Without entirely answering the question, I can say that the year comes from JSR 310, which started in 2007 - https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310 (I'm the main author of java.time.*)

Answer (score 3):

## No special meaning

No, there is no special meaning to that example date-time value. Date-time handling is tricky enough, do not distract yourself with such trivial detail.

Technical writers commonly work with the same example data across scenarios for consistency, to most easily make apparent the similarities and contrasts.

The value may have personal significance to the original author. But as [Arvind Kumar Avinash commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66426153/what-if-anything-is-the-significance-of-2007-12-03t101530-00z-in-the-java#comment117434012_66426153), what matters here is the formats rather than the value.

`2007-12-03T10:15:30.00Z` is not really an ideal example. I would have chosen a day-of-month larger than 12 to distinguish from the month number. And I would have chosen an hour larger than 12 to make obvious the 24-hour clock (0-23).

Comment: 10 & 11 are probably the least useful hours that could have been chosen.  00-09 would demonstrate the zero padding, 00 would indicate that it's 0-based, 12 would that it's a 24 hour clock (given the 0-based hour), and 13-23 would show that it's not a 24-hour clock.